# File versioning with PaperTrail and PaperClip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, paperclip, paper-trail-gem

I am trying to make some file versioning, but I cant make it work.
I have installed PaperClip and PaperTrail (and both work pretty well). What I want is to add an attribute `has_attached_file` to Version class (PaperTrail). 
So far what I've done is :

1. Added a file `paper_trail`  in `Initializers` file :

   > module PaperTrail
   >
   > class Version < ActiveRecord::Base
   >
   > attr_accessible :parent_id, :admin_edit
   >     has_attached_file :atached_file
   >     validates_attachment_content_type :atached_file,:content_type => ['image/jpeg','application/pdf']
   >   end
   >
   > end
2. Generated the attribute `atached_file` via PaperClip

   > `rails generate paperclip Versions atached_file`
3. Then when I try to use it. I have a model `TeamMember`. So what I want is to save a copy of that object (specially that image).

   > class TeamMember < ActiveRecord::Base
   >   attr_accessible :name, :title,
   >   :last_name, :picture   has_attached_file :picture, :styles => {:thumb => '100x100>'}

   From a `Form` I get the following parameters :

   > Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"345345345=",
   >   "team_member"=>{"name"=>"aaa", "last_name"=>"vv", "title"=>"ddd", 
   >       "picture"=># ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007f39f173bc98 @original_filename="rails.png", @content_type="image/png",
   >   @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data;
   >   name=\"team_member[picture]\"; filename=\"rails.png\"\r\nContent-Type:
   >   image/png\r\n",
   >   @tempfile=#>},
   >   "commit"=>"Save"}

   So, I tried to save the copy of the object with this (I omitted some code) :

   `version.atached_file = params[:picture]

    version.save`.

   But in my table Versions, the picture isn't saved, and neither in my local files.